# Sprite as a background image: how to display in bigger container?

Tags: html, css, background

I need to use sprites as a background image for element type of `<a>` tag.
The problem is that I need to display only one part of the sprite (for example 17px x 17px) and container can be higher. In this case, instead one my background image and than empty space, I get image I wanted to have and under that next image (which I don't want to display).

Is there any way to limit the `height` and `width` of the square on sprite i would like to display? I cannot set just `height` and `width` for the whole `<a> tag`.

Example:

[image]

And what i would like to do is not displaying the part from second image which is on the same sprite (its' only example; in the project i display text in the whole line, so changing width is not a solution)

Comment: can you post the screenshot what are you expecting.........

Comment: sure, I've already added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height and width for the sprite

```
a {
       display: block;
       background: url(sprite.png) no-repeat;
       height: 17px;
       width: 17px;
}
```

**EDIT** : after OP put a screehshot

You will need to use the `:before` pseudo selector along with the `content` property

Build a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/SqbnC/

```
a:before{
  background:url('http://pf.staticfil.es/hp/img/sprite2.png');
  width: 22px ;
  height: 22px;
  display:inline-block;
    content:"";
}
```

I have specified the `height` and `width` as 22px because that's the dimension of the icon that i show from the sprite

Comment: It's not a solution the whole <a href> can have more than 17 pixels (it can have more than two lines), so i cannnot limit the height

Comment: Can you specify an example of the `a`

Comment: Added to my answer. Check now

Answer (score 0):

You should use background position in your css class.
As an example..

```
.classsample{
background:url('YOUR IMAGE PATH') no-repeat 0 -20px;
height:10px;
width:10px;
}
```

Update the value 0 and -20 based on your image portion which you wanted to show in the div. And finally you should not use IMG tag on your Anchor tag, you have to pass the image via CSS class as above.

```
<a class="classsample" href="#">TEXT</a>
```

Use padding if there are no text in the Anchor tag.

Comment: it does not help when instead of 'TEXT' i will have something that will take more than 3 lines

Comment: Adding text in the a tag will cause the area of the tag make bigger.